# middleware caught exception in streamed response flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is an simple application that inserts data into a mysql db. The data gets inserted correctly but i am not getting the reponse of my post request but the status is 200.request.form works but i want to send json as payload
This is my below route and i believe something is wrong when i am checking if the keys exist in my json payload. i tried using request.json,request.get_json,request.get_json() but i am unable to get rid of this error although the status is 200 but application is not returning any message.

```
@app.route('/pythonlogin/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Output message if something goes wrong..
    msg = ''
    # current_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.get_json().get('name') != None and  request.get_json().get('password')  != None and  request.get_json().get('email')  != None and  request.get_json().get('size')!= None  :
        data = request.get_json().get
        # Create variables for easy access
        name = data('name')
        password = data('password')
        email = data('email')
        size = data('size')
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = %s', (email,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        print(account)
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists!'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address!'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', name):
            msg = 'Username must contain only characters and numbers!'
        elif not re.match(r'[0-9]',size):
            msg = 'Team size accepts only numbers'
        elif not name or not password or not email or not size:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
        else:
            print('inside else')
            role = 1
            # Account doesnt exists and the form data is valid, now insert new account into accounts table
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO company VALUES (NULL, %s,NULL, %s, %s)', (name, size,current_time))
            #cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL)', (email, password,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM company WHERE name = %s ' ,(name,))
            results = cursor.fetchone()
            comp_id = results['company_id']
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, NULL, %s,%s, %s,NULL, NULL,NULL, %s,%s)', (email, password,role,current_time,comp_id,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered!'
    else :
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
    return {"status":"1","message":msg}
```

this is my below response:

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent
```

and this

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '').
```

Comment: what's the rest of the application? and what is the output of the webserver when you send a request?

Comment: when i do 'name' in request.form['name'] ......
name = request.form['name] 
then it works but i want to send data as json not as form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i declared this twice

```
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you are using Flask-migrate, unapplied migrations also cause the same kind of exceptions. make sure you follow the below steps properly

```
flask db migrate
```

then if you skip the below step (un-apply the model changes to db). this will cause the same kind of exceptions. run the `flask db upgrade` command soon after using the `flask db migrate` command

```
flask db upgrade
```

then start the flask server and start hitting your apis.